# Logo are not displayed in Actionbar, using AppCompat

Tags: android, android-appcompat

I don't know where I missed something, but I can't set my logo in my actionbar. 
My AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<application 
    android:icon="@drawable/application_icon" 
    android:label="@string/icon_name"
    android:logo="@drawable/actionbar_logo"
    android:theme="@style/PolarTheme">
```

And also I set my logo in my activity tag in the manifest:

```
<activity 
    android:name=".Main"
    android:theme="@style/PolarThemeLogo"
    android:logo="@drawable/actionbar_logo"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan">
</activity>
```

This is in my themes.xml:

```
<style 
    name="PolarThemeLogo" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">  
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/mainColor500</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/mainColor700</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/accentColorA200</item>

    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBarLogo</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
</style>
```

My styles.xml:

```
<style name="MyActionBarLogo" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
    <item name="background">@color/mainColor500</item>
    <item name="displayOptions">useLogo</item>
</style>
```

In my Main.java:

```
public class Main extends ActionBarActivity {

@SuppressLint("NewApi")
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);    
    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setTitle("");
    actionBar.setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(true);
```

Any ideas?

**UPDATE - SOLVED**

I removed all the `android:logo` attributes from my AndroidManifest.xml and I modified my MyActionBarLogo style like this:

```
<style name="MyActionBarLogo" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar">
    <item name="background">@color/mainColor500</item>
    <item name="logo">@drawable/actionbar_logo</item>
    <item name="displayOptions">useLogo|showHome</item>
</style>
```

Now the actionbar is displaying my logo. :)

Comment: Google's documentation on point as always.

Comment: I don't believe you have to remove android:logo from your manifest, the styles should be enough.

Comment: Why are you not using style inheritence? When you use "." as a seperator the style inherets automaticcaly from its parent. F.e: PolarTheme.Logo would inherit from PolarTheme

Comment: But the icon shows middle of the actionbar, how can i set it, left side of actionbar?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I removed all the android:logo attributes from my AndroidManifest.xml and I modified my MyActionBarLogo style like this:

```
<style name="MyActionBarLogo" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar">
    <item name="background">@color/mainColor500</item>
    <item name="logo">@drawable/actionbar_logo</item>
    <item name="displayOptions">useLogo|showHome</item>
    </style>
```

Now the actionbar is displaying my logo. :)

Comment: thanx zkminusck :)  Now I can see the left arrow, logo as well as title in my action bar using "useLogo|showHome|showTitle". But there is a gap between the arrow & the logo. The logo is more close to the title, but is seen separated from the arrow. Can I move the logo a bit near to the arrow ?

Comment: I think you can if you use the new Toolbar widget and you define a custom layout for it. But check the material design guidelines first, I think it's ok if you have a gap between the arrow and the logo. Also you can check your logo picture, maybe it has too much padding on the left.

Comment: @zkminusck I  exactly need to do this too but with tabs. When I try your code, the logo is displayed but the tabs are gone. Is it somehow possible to set the navigationMode property in above theme?

Answer (score 27):

I use the following code to show the logo, hope it would be helpful.

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(true);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
getSupportActionBar().setIcon(R.drawable.logo);
```

Comment: Yup, the order of the instructions seems important, your solutions works great

Answer (score 1):

just add 3 lines in Java File and do not add code in XML and Android manifest.

```
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
```