# The application icon does not show on action bar

Tags: android, android-actionbar, icons, android-appcompat, material-design

I followed up the instructions of building a new android project and I got a runnable one except a problem with action bar. The problem is that the application icon is not showed beside the application title on action bar. I created the project with the configuration below:

- Minimum required SDK:API 8: Android 2.2(Froyo)
- Target SDK:API 21:Android 4.X(L preview)
- Compile With:API 21:Android 4.X(L preview)
- Theme:Holo Light with Dark Action Bar(Eclipse set the corresponding appcompat theme)
- Android Support Library 21.0.1
- Android SDK Build-tools 21.1.1

Because my minimum sdk is api 8 which does not support action bar, so the project includes a `appcompat_v7 library` to allow the action bar feature. If I set the minimum sdk to api 14(android 4.0) or higher, then the project does not include `appcompat_v7 library` and application icon is showed successfully also. But I need my app to support older android os as low as api 8. So what should I do to fix this problem? Really appreciate you guys attention.

P.S: I went through the task above on windows ,mac, eclipse , android studio and got the same result.

Comment: @Andrew Barber, my question is very clear and I gave the configuration to reproduce it. Its a blank android project with the config I listed above,no single line code involved and no debugging help needed coz no error at all.Its just the application icon is missing on action bar where it is supposed to be . Why do you close this question?How could that not be clear enough?

Comment: I still think it needs more information, but on your information added (which you should add to the question - which will also 'bump' it), I will go ahead and reopen.

Comment: API21 is android 5, not 4.x. Also which version of appcompat ? are you using the Holo theme or the appcompat theme? Post more details.

Comment: @Gabriele Mariotti,API 21 is android 5.0 indeed.But the eclipse ADT plugin only offers me "API 21:Android 4.X(L preview)" to choose which also kinda confuse me. Im using  the newest appcompat-v7(Android Support Library 21.0.1) and the appcompat theme in it, both are included and configured to the project automatically by eclipse.

Comment: @Gabriele Mariotti,I tried doing the same thing on windows,mac, eclipse,android studio and got the same result. Could you create a new android project with my configuration to see if this problem also happen?

Comment: @Andrew Barber,thank you. I will try to add more details to my question. But for the problem arises from a blanket project, its really hard to tell much about it.

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26472417/logo-are-not-displayed-in-actionbar-using-appcompat

Answer (score 60, accepted):

You are using the `AppCompat` version 21+ and it is normal.

The Action Bar follows the **material design guidelines** and uses a [Toolbar](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/Toolbar.html).
As you can read [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/Toolbar.html):

> The use of application icon plus title as a standard layout is
>   discouraged on API 21 devices and newer.

If you would like an application icon (but I discourage it), you can use the method `setLogo()`.

Something like this:

```
ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
actionBar.setLogo(R.drawable.my_logo);
actionBar.setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(true);
actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
```

Comment: I have tried setLogo but still not work.Here is my code:                   `@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
  ActionBar ab =getSupportActionBar();
  ab.setLogo(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
  
  
  
 }
`

Comment: If I set the minimum sdk to api 14(android 4.0) or higher, then appcompat wont be included and application icon shows successfully without any corresponding code like setLogo.

Comment: Without the appcompat you are using a standard ActionBar (with Holo Thme), so it is normal.

Comment: But why setLogo() method does not work with appcompat?could this be a bug of AppCompat 21?

Comment: Here is another man bothered by this question.[http://antonioleiva.com/material-design-everywhere/] (max2817) But right now at least I know its normal and recommended by your answer. Maybe after more people join lollipop then I can find the final answer.

Comment: Thanks it's working now, but how can i move the logo in center of actionbar?

Comment: using actionbar will adjust itself with activity and related stuff, but for toolbar your have adjust it

Answer (score 48):

This issue comes when you use support library revised 21.

Use:

```
ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
actionBar.setLogo(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
actionBar.setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(true);
actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
```

It worked for me or you can use toolbar. A Toolbar is a generalization of action bars for use within application layouts.

In modern Android UIs developers should lean more on a visually distinct color scheme for toolbars than on their application icon. The use of application icon plus title as a standard layout is discouraged on API 21 devices and newer.

Reference: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/Toolbar.html

Comment: Thank you.
One question, is it backward/forward compatible?

Answer (score 9):

Make sure you have the icon set in the manifest.xml file, in the application tag as:

```
    android:icon="@drawable/launcher_icon"
```

Then in the onCreate method insert the following lines:

```
    ActionBar ab =getSupportActionBar(); 
    ab.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
    ab.setIcon(R.drawable.launcher_icon);
```

Comment: why do we have to define it at two places??

Answer (score 4):

This is a common "problem".Before you pull your hairs out make sure you are using:

```
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar; //or the v4, haven't tried with that though
```

and not:

```
import android.app.ActionBar;
```

and then:

```
ActionBar actionBar;
actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
```

instead of:

`actionBar = getActionBar();`

And finally:

```
if (actionBar != null) {
        // enabling action bar app icon and behaving it as toggle button           
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setIcon(R.drawable.your_icon);
        actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
    }
```

Comment: This worked for me. Thanks. There really should be an easier way to preserve style elements of your apps.

Answer (score 2):

Attribute logo is only used in API level 11 and higher (current min is 8), I was also confused about this question, maybe google just don't want the icon to show on material design, when the minimum sdk is set to 14 or higher and under 21,it uses holo theme, it has an icon, but appcompat style is more like material design I think, maybe google just forget to modify the holo theme

Comment: yes,its no problem they hide the icon by default but at least they should offer us a way to show it manually.

Answer (score 2):

IN Style.xml

```
 <style name="MyTheme_ActionBar" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
   <item name="icon">@drawable/actionbar_logo</item>
  </style>
```

In activity add this and try

```
ActionBar mActionBar = getSupportActionBar();
mActionBar.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_HOME_AS_UP |
                             ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM |
                             ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_HOME);
```