# Android: Icon doesn't appear in ActionBar

Tags: android

I'm programming an android application and since the first moment the icon doesn't appear on the Action Bar. I've already read/applied lots of possible solutions but it doesn't appear. Can you please help me?

Manifest.xml:

```
(...)
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
(...)
```

styles.xml:

```
(...)
   <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="android:icon">@drawable/ic_launcher</item>
    </style>
```

and I'm using the following configuration:

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.converter.android.converter"
    minSdkVersion 11
    targetSdkVersion 21
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
```

Comment: "I've already read/applied lots of possible solutions but it doesn't appear" -- you are going to be closed as a duplicate of [things like this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26850864/115145) if you do not explain **completely and precisely** what you tried.

Comment: @CommonsWare, I've tried to Change parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar" in **style.xml**.
Also tried 
        ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
But this is only possible to API 14.

Comment: I think this is related with the theme I'm using..

Answer (score 1):

If you are using AppCompat theme in your application, then the app icon won't be visible on Action bar.

As you can see the Google's apps with material design, there isn't any app icon on ActionBar.

But if you want to add app icon, try using toolbar and hide actionbar.

Comment: Thanks!!! Your first sentence told me something that I suspect about AppCompat theme. With it I could find the solution. This was the solution to my problem:

        getSupportActionBar().setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);

Answer (score 0):

> Also tried ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar(); actionBar.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher) But this is only possible to API 14

If you are using `appcompat-v7`, as your theme suggests, you call `getSupportActionBar()` on your `ActionBarActivity`, not `getActionBar()`.