# Application's icon not displayed in ActionBar

Tags: android, android-actionbar, icons

I'm new in the Android programming world, and I don't understand why the system is not displaying the application icon on the left side of the 'ActionBar' of my first Android application (HelloWorld).

In the 'ActionBar' developer guide it's stated that:
"By default, the system uses your application icon in the action bar, as specified by the icon attribute in the "application" or "activity" element. However, if you also specify the logo attribute, then the action bar uses the logo image instead of the icon."
([Action bar](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#Logo)))

My Android-manifest file isn't defining a 'logo' attribute, but it defines just an 'icon' attribute. Therefore, the icon defined by the 'icon' attribute should be displayed on the left side of the 'ActionBar' as the application icon. However, no icon is being displayed.

My Android-manifest file is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.holamundo"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0">

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppBaseTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
</manifest>
```

And my style files are the following:

/res/values/styles.xml:

```
<resources>
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">    
</style>
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">        
</style>
</resources>
```

/res/values-v11/styles.xml:

```
<resources>
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
</style>
</resources>
```

/res/values-v14/styles.xml:

```
<resources>
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
</style>
</resources>
```

Can anyone explain me why my application icon is not being displayed in the ActionBar and what should I modify in order to such an icon be displayed? Thanks.

Comment: You are using the appcompat v21. Check here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26838730/the-application-icon-does-not-show-on-action-bar/26850864#26850864

Comment: Yes, i am. what's the problem about using such library? 
My question remains unanswered. 'appcompat_v7' library provides the 'ActionBar' class in the package 'android.support.v7.app' and the purpose of such library is supporting the use of features like the 'ActionBar' feature on Android 2.1 (API level 7) and higher devices. So, i don't find any reason why i cannot use the 'ActionBar' feature.

Comment: Moreover, I've found some code snippets that make the app icon be displayed on the 'ActionBar', so my guess is that the app icon is displayed in an 'ActionBar' item, not in a 'ToolBar' item.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your activity must extend ActionBarActivity.

For example:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity
{
...
}
```

Or try this in your activity:

```
ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
actionBar.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_HOME | ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_TITLE);
actionBar.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
```

You will have to use getSupportActionBar() if using the support library.

Comment: It might be helpful to expand on your answer a bit by actually showing the code that relates to your suggestion.

Comment: Your code made my app icon be displayed in the ActionBar. It's ok. But my initial question remains unanswered: why do I need to include this code snippet in order to the app icon be displayed?

Comment: Appcombat-v7 automatically disables DISPLAY_SHOW_HOME so you must set it to true or add it to the display options to show an icon.

Comment: Interesting! Could you provide some reference where such a behaviour is stated?

Comment: AppCombat version 21 follows the material design guidelines for the ActionBar and uses a Toolbar. See Class Overview of ToolBar: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/Toolbar.html
"The use of application icon plus title as a standard layout is discouraged on API 21 devices and newer."

Comment: Interesting! But where exactly it's stated that 'Appcompat-v7 automatically disables DISPLAY_SHOW_HOME'?

Comment: I am not sure. Similar questions to this one have popped up before on StackOverflow and I saw that some answers said this so I went searching and that is all I could find. I remember having this same problem before myself and that is the code I had to use to resolve it.

Comment: Ok, no problem, thank you very much anyway. Do you know any way of making the app icon be displayed in the Actionbar|Toolbar without using any piece of code; that is, just using xml attributes?

Comment: Something like this should work in the xml file that represents your ActionBar in your resources/menu folder: `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 

   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
<item 
    android:id="@+id/home1"
    android:orderInCategory="0"
    android:icon="@drawable/home_icon"
    android:title="Navigate to Home"

    app:showAsAction="always"/>

</menu>`

Comment: The effect is not the same as the one got by using the snippet code you posted in your answer, that is, the app icon is not placed in the usual place for app icons. :(

Comment: You could try add something like this to your styles.xml file:

Comment: `<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light" />
<style name="WATheme" parent="Theme.Sherlock.Light">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/WATheme.ActionBar</item>
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/WATheme.ActionBar</item>
    <item name="android:icon">@drawable/ic_menu</item>
    <item name="icon">@drawable/ic_menu</item>
</style>
<style name="WATheme.ActionBar" parent="Widget.Sherlock.Light.ActionBar.Solid">
    <item name="android:displayOptions">homeAsUp|showHome|showTitle</item>
    <item name="displayOptions">homeAsUp|showHome|showTitle</item>
</style>`

Answer (score 0):

I've also been having the problem where a menu item icon is not being displayed.  I have a toolbar and I set it up to be the support action bar. The manifest declares a NoActionBar theme. Originally I thought that none of the icons for action items would display, however, I've discovered that some drawable icons would display.  For, example  "@android:drawable/ic_menu_add" would work, but "drawable/ic_launcher_background" would not work.  Here's the menu structure that I inflate during the onCreateOptionsMenu.  The item action_logo uses a png file and that one works too.  The 'ic_launcher_background" is a drawable that is automagically added when the project was created.

```
  <item
    android:id="@+id/action_help"
    android:orderInCategory="50"
    android:title="@string/action_help"
    android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_add"
    app:showAsAction="always" />
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_more"
    android:orderInCategory="60"
    android:title="@string/action_help"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher_background"
    app:showAsAction="always" />
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_logo"
    android:orderInCategory="70"
    android:title="@string/action_help"
    android:icon="@drawable/tabellae_logo"
    app:showAsAction="always" />
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_settings"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:title="@string/action_settings"
    app:showAsAction="never" />
```

What I've been trying to do was to generate a BitmapDrawable on the fly an add it to the menu during a onPrepareOptionsMenu call, but that kind of drawable won't display either.

I have different test application that has it's manifest set to an ActionBarTheme.  In this configuration, you don't need to call setSupportActionBar. (It's error if you try to do so)  Now this test application displays all the menu icons correctly.  It is an AppCompatActivity application.  My guess is that this test application is probably using the old style ActionBar rather then the newly recommended ToolBar approach and that's why it works.

My preference is to use the ToolBar approach, but I don't have an explanation why some icon drawables work and other do not. In my research on this problem, I've not seen anyone mention these observations.  Perhaps someone would have more insight into why certain drawables don't work for menu item icons.

Comment: I feel like a silly goof!  But I've discovered the problem.  The icons were displaying, but my test app was configured for a DarkActionBar.  The icons that weren't displaying were probably picking up the theme background color so I just could see them.  The drawable icon that I created on the fly had a black color.  I thought it would show up even against the dark actionbar background.  But it turns out that I generated it too small and it was  and it wasn't big enough to see with the dark actionbar background.