# ActionBar does not show the app icon

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I´m working with the `ActionBar` in Android, I have an `MainActivity` that extends from `ActionBarActivity`, them, I had put an icon on the right side and works perfectly, but when I try to set the app icon (on the left of the `ActionBar`) I get nothing. My actionBar just shows the name of my app.

I put in my `Manifest.xml` this:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        package="com.training.cloudmas.appone" >

        <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/main_icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MyActivity"
        android:icon="@drawable/main_icon"
        android:logo="@drawable/main_icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".DisplayMessageActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_display_message"
        android:parentActivityName=".MyActivity" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.training.cloudmas.appone.MyActivity" />
    </activity>
        </application>

    </manifest>
```

I was trying wiht android:logo, android:icon, etc... but doesn´t work.

In my MainActiviy I put this:

```
 ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(true);
   // actionBar.setLogo(R.drawable.main_icon);
    actionBar.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_HOME |         ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_TITLE);
```

As you can see I was trying with a lot of methods, but no one works. I put an icon in my actionbar, but just was a normal icon, and it appears on the center of my actionbar.

Please, I have 2 hours with this and I can´t get nothing.

Comment: Are you targeting Android 5? The new Material design does not feature an icon in the actionbar.

Comment: setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);

there are links which can help you to investigate 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26838730/the-application-icon-does-not-show-on-action-bar

Comment: Im using the min api 14, and max 22.

Answer (score 2):

Use this programatically :

```
   getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
                getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
```

and following in manifest in application tag :

```
android:icon="@drawable/map_img"
```

Comment: I used this, but I just can see an arrow, I would like change the arrow to an icon, I put the android:icon in the manifest and I goint to try with android:logo, but I dont know if I forget something.