# Logo not showing in Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar style

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-appcompat

I cant see the logo in my application when i use DarkActionBar style.

my style file looks like this

```
    <!-- the theme applied to the application or activity -->
<style name="AppTheme"
    parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>

    <!-- Support library compatibility -->
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
</style>
```

and in the manifest i have:

```
   <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/logo"
    android:label="@string/title_activity_main"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
```

thanks for help..

Comment: see this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26720759/no-app-icon-on-actionbar

Comment: With appCompat v21+ is normal. Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26838730/the-application-icon-does-not-show-on-action-bar/26850864#26850864