# Get Logo to left in ActionBar

Tags: android, android-layout, android-actionbar-compat

First I have to say that I know this isn't correct anymore to the Google Guidelines. But still I need to know it.

I'm trying to Add the Android Icon in my ActionBar.
[Logo are not displayed in Actionbar, using AppCompat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26472417/logo-are-not-displayed-in-actionbar-using-appcompat)

This gave my the answer. But my problem now is that the logo is in the middle of the ActionBar. I want it in the left.

Code:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBarLogo</item>
</style>

<style name="MyActionBarLogo" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar">
    <item name="background">@color/background_material_dark</item>
    <item name="logo">@drawable/icon</item>
    <item name="displayOptions">useLogo|showHome</item>
</style>
```

Printscreen:

[image: PrintScreen]

Anyone an idea?
I have the feeling it's something stupid...

EDIT: Added Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.ap.brecht.myapplication" >

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
            >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Any way you could make that picture a little smaller? ;-)

Comment: android:logo check for this in manifest and remove

Comment: @apk: There isn't any logo in the manifest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah I found the problem.
It's really stupid!

The size of the icon was much to big!
After changing it to 48 * 48 it works!

Comment: That solved my problem too. Only ImageView with a fixed width can be set with layout_gravity left/right on toolbar

Answer (score 2):

why don't u use **Toolbar**?

I think in your case you should use toolbar.

Here is sample code...

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
    android:theme="@style/Toolbar"
    android:background="@color/primary"
    app:theme="@style/Toolbar">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/toolbarTitle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:textSize="22dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"/>

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

that's my toolbar with textview in the middle of toolbar. 
You can put whatever you want instead of **TextView** I used
Hope this will help u.

Comment: Thanks for giving me the tip about the Toolbar.
Now I realize that this it the way to be. 

But I can't change my hole app now. But I will use this in the future.
I'm a newbie at Android. I'm coming from C# Win32.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a logo in vector format ***.svg**. and it will work.