# How to set actionBar image with @style

Tags: android, background, android-actionbar, styles

I'm trying to set drawable as image for actionBar in my activity, using @style, but don't see any result... 
This is my @styles:

```
<resources>
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBarTheme</item>
</style>

<style name="MyCustomTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBarTheme</item>
</style>

<style name="MyActionBarTheme" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/bgd</item>
</style>
```

This is my activity code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:theme="@style/MyCustomTheme"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">


<com.roughike.bottombar.BottomBar
    android:id="@+id/bottomBar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="52dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    app:bb_behavior="shifting|underNavbar"
    app:bb_tabXmlResource="@xml/bottombar_tabs_main_screen"/>
```

Thas's what I have:

[image]

That's that actionBar, I want to get:

[image]

Comment: Have you included MyCustomTheme  style in your manifest ?

Comment: What is your App theme? Have you used Theme.AppCompat for related Activity or App theme? Can you provide your menifest code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was like this (as I'm using AppCompat):

1. My styles:

   @style/ActionBar
       @style/ActionBar

   @drawable/bgd
       @drawable/bgd
       @mipmap/ic_launcher_round
       @mipmap/ic_launcher_round
       useLogo|showHome

2.I had to revome any logo atributes from my Manifest file;
3. You can see here [Logo are not displayed in Actionbar, using AppCompat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26472417/logo-are-not-displayed-in-actionbar-using-appcompat)

Answer (score 0):

Im'm trying to use it in exact activity, this is my manifest:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="org.workout.mauzerthecat.vesortupdate">

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
              android:theme="@style/MyCustomTheme">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Same result;