# Show Logo and Icon in ActionBar

Tags: android, android-studio, android-actionbar

Hello

I have a problem.

In my Android-Project I have a Action Bar.

I would have a logo and a icon, but if I take the logo, it is just the logo and not also the icon.

```
if (getSupportActionBar() != null) {
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setIcon(ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.mipmap.ic_launcher));
        getSupportActionBar().setLogo(R.drawable.logo_text);
}
```

If i just take "getSupportActionBar().setIcon(ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.mipmap.ic_launcher));" and not "getSupportActionBar().setLogo(R.drawable.logo_text);", then there is a icon.

What must I do?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Logo are not displayed in Actionbar, using AppCompat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26472417/logo-are-not-displayed-in-actionbar-using-appcompat)

Comment: No, in my case the icon is not displayed.